# Mapping object that contains a ptr_map of abstract base classes

Tags: c++, abstract-class, stdmap, boost-ptr-container

I have a `boost::ptr_map` which stores abstract base class (e.g. [VectorWrapperBase](https://gist.github.com/2643718)) as values and this allows me to map strings to vectors of different types.

```
boost::ptr_map<std::string, VectorWrapperBase> memory_map;
//...
memory_map.insert(str_key, new VectorWrapper<T>());
```

This appears to work. However, when I have `memory_map` as a member of another class and attempt to store that class in an `std::map`, compilation fails.

```
class AgentMemory {
  //...
  private:
    boost::ptr_map<std::string, VectorWrapperBase> memory_map;
};

std::map<std::string, AgentMemory> agent_map;
//...
agent_map.insert(std::pair<std::string, AgentMemory>(agent_name, AgentMemory()));
```

The last line fails with:

```
/SOMEPATH/boost_1_48_0/boost/ptr_container/clone_allocator.hpp:34
   error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘xyz::VectorWrapperBase’
```

Being new to C++, this is baffling.

I *suspect* that error is down to the map insertion copying the `AgentMemory` object which involves cloning the `ptr_map`. And since my `VectorWrapper` objects are not [cloneable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html#cloneability), the error is raised.

My questions are:

- Why am I getting the error? (Are my suspicions even close to what's actually happening?)
- How do I address this?

To address the compilation error, I've considered the following, but without much experience with C++ can't decide which is more appropriate:

1. Remove the pure specifier (`= 0`) so `VectorWrapperBase` is no longer abstract

   - This feels like a hack since `VectorWrapperBase` should never be instantiated
2. Make the VectorWrappers [cloneable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html#cloneability)

   - [This seems to work](https://gist.github.com/2644367), but in my use case only empty containers are assigned to the top-level map so VectorWrappers within the inner `ptr_map` need never be cloned. The cloneability would therefore be there just to appease the compiler and does not reflect the actual usage.
3. Forget `ptr_map` and use a `std::map` and `shared_ptr` instead.

   - I'm less keen on this solution as I would like the lifetime of the vector wrappers to be linked to that of the map. I'm also a little concerned (perhaps unnecessarily so?) about the potential overheads of extensive use of `shared_ptr` in a heavily multi-threaded application.

Comment: does your Abstract Base Class have a virtual destructor?

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
agent_map.insert(std::pair<std::string, AgentMemory>(agent_name, AgentMemory()));
```

will call the default constructor of `AgentMemory`, which in turn will call the default constructor of `boost::ptr_map<std::string, VectorWrapperBase>`, which will try to call the non-existent constructor for the abstract base class `VectorWrapperBase`.

So you have to make sure that every constructor of types wrapping or inheriting `VectorWrapperBase` should always construct a concrete derived class. In your case, option 3 (a map of shared pointers to derived classes) could be sensible, but that depends on the larger context of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What confuses me is that the `ptr_map` starts off empty so why is there a need to call the constructor for `VectorWrapperBase`?

Comment: @ShawnChin As I explained in my answer, the `insert()` call with the `AgentMemory()` argument will generate the constructor call.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, but `VectorWrapperBase` is not a member of `AgentMemory` and so I don't see why an instance of it should be created. That said, I now appreciate the fact that `VectorWrapperBase` needs to be cloneable since the `ptr_map` needs to be copied by the copy constructor of the encapsulating class.